# How to find the default applications in android?

Tags: android, default

I have an android application which lists the system and installed apps of a device.Also launch the selected one on click.It works fine.Now i want to disable listing of following applications.

1. `Task Manager`(which shows on long pressing home button)
2. `Settings`

These are the names used in Samsung Galaxy devices.I want to get the package name and launcher activity name of the application using for these purpose in `Sony Ericson`,`Google phones`,`HTC` and `Samsung` devices.

Also i want the package name of applications `Camera`,`Email` & `Gmail` using in these devices.

In short :  I want to get the package name of these applications in the specified device because there are many apps can be use for a single purpose.For eg : ,There are many apps which can be use as a Task Manager, also we can change the default task manager and use a custom app for this purpose.So i don,t know which is used in users device.We can find the home launcher applications using Intent and ResolverActivity.Like this is there any way to get list of all applications which can be use as task manager,camera handling applications etc...?

Any help  is much appreaciating.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see task manager and settings dont have package name you can disable task manager by using this code

```
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    Log.d("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

if(!hasFocus) {
    Log.d("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");

    Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
}
}
```

and settings goto by using

```
 startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

By using you can disale and enable. By last gmail,Email,camera you search by net and used in your code.

All the Best:)

Answer (score 0):

Go to google play store and install package name viewer(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gijoon.pkgnameviewer&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5naWpvb24ucGtnbmFtZXZpZXdlciJd) you can see package name for each and every application.

Comment: Is it shows package name of installed application of the current device?I want make my application works in all devices.

Comment: I can't understand your question can you please edit and put some screenshots its easy to clarify your doubts?